# After recording a script in JMeter I am not able to play back. Not able to login.

Tags: jmeter

After recording a script in JMeter I am not able to play back. Not able to login. can someone help. The form_key was dynamic I was able to use regular expression extractor to capture form_key. But now the username, password and login is not getting passed.

Comment: <input name="login[username]" value="" id="email" type="email" class="icon-input form-control" required placeholder="Email Address" />
<input name="login[password]" type="password" id="pass" value="" class="form-control hideShowPassword-field icon-input" data-validate-minlength="6" required placeholder="Password" />
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" name="send" id="send2">Login</button>

Answer (score 0):

Do you send your parameters?

Are you sure that you don't need to use HTTP Cookie manager?